# cucumber's web_step#follow using capybara produces a NameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, capybara

Does anyone know why I get the following error when I use the web_step#follow method?

```
When I follow "Stuff" within "#main-nav"               # features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:33
  undefined local variable or method `node' for #<Capybara::Driver::RackTest::Node:0x00000101409b40> (NameError)
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:35:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `block in with_scope'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
  ./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:34:in `/^(?:|I )follow "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
```

This is the html output:

```
<ul id='main-nav'> 
  <li><a href="/things">Things</a></li> 
  <li><a href="/stuff">Stuff</a></li> 
</ul>
```

P.S. I have removed webrat and am solely using capybara

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be really helpful if you showed the *actual* code you were using, so that we're both debugging the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

per: https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/issues/110

comment out this line in `env.rb`:

`require 'cucumber/rails/capybara_javascript_emulation'`

Note: after commenting that line you'll have to explicitly tag your features/scenarios with `@javascript` if you want to click links with onclick javascript handlers.

See also: https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber-rails/issues/77 which eventually takes you on a journey to discover it should be fixed in `cucumber-rails v0.4.0` (2011-03-20).  This may still be relevant for folks with `Rails 2.3.x` projects using `cucumber-rails v0.3.2`

Answer (score 1):

This means that the actual output of your page does not include the element you're trying to search for. For example, if you had `with_scope("#my_div")` but your content didn't have any divs with the id `my_div` it would raise this exception.

I'd suggest trying to add a cucumber step of `Then show me the page` before the failing step, and investigate the source of the generated page.

Comment: Thanks for the tip re. 'show me the page'! Please see my updated post